# Using a variable in batch file to store a command then execute it

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am new to batch files. Basically what I need to do is something like this

`if %1==choice1 set command=dir
 if %1==choice2 set command=rmdir
 %command% /q /s`

any ideas?

Comment: Any ideas is not really a question.  You need to ask questions about specific code.  The `DIR` command will run fine.  The `rmdir` command will not run because you have not supplied it a directory to remove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not clear about what you need. Please be more specific. 
To compare input an save command to variable, use:

```
if "%1"=="choice1" set "command=dir" 
if "%1"=="choice2" set "command=rmdir /q /s PATH_TO_DELETE"
```

To run the command later, just use:

```
%command%
```

I highly suggest you put a unique identifier on your variable name, like my_saved_command instead of using a common word like command by itself.